# Why my callback function in the following script never get called?

Tags: python, tornado, future, jupyter, pyzmq

In following script why my callback function never get called ?
I am using a pre-created kernel to run the code and trying to get the output of it with attaching the callback for respective sockets.

```
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
ioloop.install()
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
from functools import partial
from tornado import gen
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from jupyter_client import BlockingKernelClient
from pprint import pprint
import logging, os, zmq

reply_futures = {}

context = zmq.Context()
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
publisher.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5253")

def reply_callback(session, stream, msg_list):
    idents, msg_parts = session.feed_identities(msg_list)
    reply = session.deserialize(msg_parts)
    parent_id = reply['parent_header'].get('msg_id')
    reply_future = reply_futures.get(parent_id)
    print("{} \n".format(reply))
    if reply_future:
        if "execute_reply" == reply["msg_type"]:
            reply_future.set_result(reply)
    publisher.send(reply)

def fv_execute():
    code = 'print ("hello")'
    msg_id = execute(code)
    return msg_id

def get_connection_file(kernel_id):
    json_file = 'kernel-{}.json'.format(kernel_id)
    return os.path.join('/tmp',json_file)

def execute(code,):
    kernel_id = '46459cb4-fa34-497a-8e3d-dfb3ab4476fd'
    cf = get_connection_file(kernel_id)
    kernel_client = BlockingKernelClient(connection_file=cf)
    setup_listener(kernel_client)
    msg_id = ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda:         execute_(kernel_client,code))
    return msg_id

def setup_listener(kernel_client):
    shell_stream = ZMQStream(kernel_client.shell_channel.socket)
    iopub_stream = ZMQStream(kernel_client.iopub_channel.socket)
    shell_stream.on_recv_stream(partial(reply_callback,     kernel_client.session))
    iopub_stream.on_recv_stream(partial(reply_callback, kernel_client.session))

@gen.coroutine
def execute_(kernel_client, code):
    msg_id = kernel_client.execute(code)
    f = reply_futures[msg_id] = Future()
    print("Is kernel alive: {}".format(kernel_client.is_alive()))
    print(msg_id)
    yield f
    raise gen.Return(msg_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fv_execute()
```

here is output, the script runs forever

```
jupyter@albus:~/lab$ python2 iolooptest2.py
Is kernel alive: True
de3eae2e-48d3-451a-b6bc-421674bb2a35
^X^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "iolooptest2.py", line 61, in <module>
    fv_execute()
  File "iolooptest2.py", line 30, in fv_execute
    msg_id = execute(code)
  File "iolooptest2.py", line 42, in execute
    msg_id = ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda:     execute_(kernel_client,code))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py",  line 452, in run_sync
    self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-     packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line  862, in start
    event_pairs = self._impl.poll(poll_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 122, in poll
    z_events = self._poller.poll(1000*timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/poll.py", line 99, in poll
    return zmq_poll(self.sockets, timeout=timeout)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/_poll.pyx", line 116, in  zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll (zmq/backend/cython/_poll.c:2036)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 12, in  zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/_poll.c:2418)
 KeyboardInterrupt
```

A slightly modified version of the code is here 
https://gist.github.com/jayendra13/76a4f5726428882013ea62d94974da5c
where I pass `ioloop` as a argument to `zmqstream`, while attaching the callback, which also has a same behaviour.

Here is almost similar script which works
https://gist.github.com/jayendra13/e553fafba5398e287107e947c16988df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following two lines after the creation of kernel_client solved my issue.

```
    kernel_client.load_connection_file()
    kernel_client.start_channels()
```

so new `execute` looks like this

```
def execute(code,):
    kernel_id = '46459cb4-fa34-497a-8e3d-dfb3ab4476fd'
    cf = get_connection_file(kernel_id)
    kernel_client = BlockingKernelClient(connection_file=cf)
    kernel_client.load_connection_file()
    kernel_client.start_channels()
    setup_listener(kernel_client)
    msg_id = ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda:         execute_(kernel_client,code))
    return msg_id
```